# How to put several images in one row in LaTex?

Tags: graphics

I want to know how to put 3 images in one row in Latex, so that it looks like the following format:
[image]

Anyone can help me! Thank you so much!

Note: The figures need to span two columns inside a `multicols` environment.

Comment: `\includegraphics{}` is positioned like `X` just put three next to each other and they come in a row.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, can you give me an example?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I tried "\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig1.jpg, fig2.jpg, fig3.jpg }", but it does not work

Comment: `\includegraphics{fig1}\includegraphics{fig2}\includegraphics{fig3}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle,my figures are too big, the command works, but cannot display the third figures. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: You can use the scale options as you have shown already, put `[width=1cm]` on each one and all three will fit in 3cm.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the figures are not in the middle of the paper. and I want some spaces between the images. How to achieve this?

Comment: as I say they are positioned exactly like a letter you can use `\centering` to centre them, and put \hspace{2in} or \hfill or just a space character between them, there are literally thousands of examples of graphics inclusion on this site

Comment: Sounds like the question forgot to mention he's asking how to span three images across two columns?

Comment: @Ryan, yes, Please tell me how to span 3 images across two columns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to position figures across the columns of `multicol`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{figure*}[ht!]
            \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
            \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
            \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
            \caption{Image A.}
            \caption{Image B.}
            \caption{Image C.}
        \end{figure*}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Note that I'm using the starred version of the `figure` environment. The `[ht]` tag specifies position, here indicating "at the top of this page." Google "LaTeX Floats" for how to change that and how to adjust the `figure` environment.

Here: copy\paste only this part:

```
        \begin{figure*}[ht!]
            \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
            \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfill
            \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
            \caption{Image A.}
            \caption{Image B.}
            \caption{Image C.}
        \end{figure*}
```

Comment: I use exactly your command. There is one error :  ! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \begin{document}

Comment: And in my paper, there are lots of unrecognized characters above and under the 3 images. They looks like this: consectetuer adipiscing elit.
In hac habitasse platea
dictumst. Integer tempus
convallis augue. Etiam
facilisis. Nunc elementum
fermentum wisi. Aenean
placerat. Ut imperdiet,
enim sed gravida sollicitudin,
felis odio placerat
quam, ac pulvinar elit
purus eget enim. Nunc
vitae tortor. Proin tempus
nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus
quis tortor vitae risus porta

Comment: @user3761566 Well... did you paste the whole thing in, including my documentclass, usepackage commands, and begin document? if so, there's your problem...

Comment: ...I've used lorem ipsum from `lipsum` as an example, you don't need to put that in your document...

Comment: @user3761566 See my edit now, I've separated the solution from the example...

Comment: See my edit, I separated the bit you want...

Comment: well, did you replace "example-image-a" "example-image-b" and "example-image-c" with your images?

Comment: change the [ht!] tag then, you have [h] in yours, try that.

Comment: see my answer, it tells you what to google to find out how to control the position of the float

Comment: This explains how the positioning works http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions

Comment: Because you didn't post an MWE or anything, I can't really help you further.

Comment: Here, this addresses your problem exactly: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Wide_figures_in_two_column_documents

Comment: Your question does not contain compilable LaTeX code, so any answers are merely guesses—we can't recreate any of your problems.

Comment: Please read the articles I linked, they are the solutions to your problems. TeX.SE generally frowns upon questions that are simply solved by reading the wiki or other common sources.

Answer (score 9):

I just prepared a question/answer (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361579/)) and I think that the code is suitable for the question here. I provide different examples that are based on the `subcaption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    showframe, % This option shows the margins and so on -- remove it in the final version
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% Here: H option for float placement
\usepackage{float}

% caption and subcaption work together
\usepackage{subcaption} % loads the caption package

\begin{document}

\section{Two Figures}
\subsection{Horizontal}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Vertical}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\section{Three Figures}
\subsection{Horizontal}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Vertical}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Mixed}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\section{Four Figures}
\subsection{Horizontal}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Mixed}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\section{Symmetric Padding}

See the following example with small picture widths.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

You can use the optional argument of the \texttt{\textbackslash subcaptionbox} in order to define the width of the sub element.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}[0.50\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}[0.50\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}[0.50\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}[0.50\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

Here I try to illustrate the idea behind the solution -- \textbf{don't use this code}!

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\fbox{%
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}[0.482\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\fbox{%
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}[0.482\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\fbox{%
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}[0.482\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\fbox{%
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}[0.482\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image}}%
}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do what you want maybe it is not the best but it does the work, use multicol package and just play with the \columsep and the scale of the image and for the figure name use caption package as the code below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}[\columnsep=3cm]
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figura}
\columnbreak
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figura}
\columnbreak
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figura}
\end{multicols}
\captionof{figure}{Name of the figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the result don't take to much attention to the cat it was the first image I can find, Hope it helps

Comment: I am writing two columns format paper, I input your command, they are not in a row and they are in the left column. I want the three images in one row ,which occupy two columns. Can you modify your command?

Comment: Also, I want to add descriptions below the three images

Comment: \*heavy breathing*

Answer (score 1):

To do this in LaTeX, I think you want to take a look at the `subfig` package.  The documentation is clear and well-written, and it seems to provide the facilities you want.  That, combined with Ryan's answer about figures spanning columns in `multicol`, should get you what you want.  (Ryan's answer will also get you there by itself; but there is a package for that, as there usually is.)

But TeX works simply by shoving boxes together in various ways, sometimes with certain amounts of space between them; that space can be rigid (a "skip") or variable ("glue," which can stretch or shrink as required by the typesetting).  Those boxes come in two forms:  `\hbox`es, which are horizontally-oriented; and `\vbox`es, which are vertically oriented.  These can be nested more or less infinitely (not really, as TeX's memory is limited, but there's no conceptual limit).

E.g., consider a paragraph.  Every letter is a box; the spaces between the words and the lines are glue (they stretch or shrink within certain limits); and TeX puts them together into horizontal boxes (each line) and a vertical box (the lines arranged into a paragraph) based on its complex system of penalties which leads to the best results.

This is done automatically with paragraph-typesetting; but it can be done manually, too, by explicitly setting the boxes.  And box-twiddling is super-fun, so let's see how we can do that in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\hbox to\linewidth{%
    \hfil%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Bo0MI.jpg}%
    \hfil%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Bo0MI.jpg}%
    \hfil%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Bo0MI.jpg}%
    \hfil%
}
\end{document}
```

As for putting a caption under each image, it looks like a caption already *is* part of your image; but if you want something besides what's already there, you can do this in a number of ways.  E.g., with direct box-twiddling:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\hbox to\linewidth{%
    \hfil%
    \vbox{%
        \hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Bo0MI.jpg}}%
        \hbox{Some caption here.}
    }%
    \hfil%
    \vbox{%
        \hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Bo0MI.jpg}}%
        \hbox{Another caption here.}
    }%
    \hfil%
    \vbox{%
        \hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Bo0MI.jpg}}%
        \hbox{A third caption here.}
    }%
    \hfil%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Spaced images with captions.]

Of course, if this is anything more than a one-off, you'd want to define a new command for it; but since `subfig` has already done that, you can skip the overhead.  There's no need to reinvent the wheel.

There's a lot more to boxes than just this, but that's the concept behind things.  Any good TeX reference can tell you more.