# subcaption: Calculating the Width

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

- A friend writes his master thesis and asked me for help.
- He wants to use sub figures.
- **"No problem" I said...two hours later here we are :)**
- I thought that the `subcaption` package is the best suited for this task.
- I tried to prepare a nice collection of examples and encountered a problem with the calculation of the width.
- **Problem:** According to my (apparently wrong) thinking, I have a sum of 100 % but I get a line break.
- I need to have less than 100 % in order to have all figures in one line.

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% Here: H option for float placement
\usepackage{float}

% caption and subcaption work together
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\section*{Two Figures}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hspace{0.1\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
45\,\% + 10\,\% + 45\,\% = 100\,\%
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.44\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hspace{0.1\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.44\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
44\,\% + 10\,\% + 44\,\% = 98\,\%
\end{equation}

\pagebreak
\section*{Three Figures}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
30\,\% + 5\,\% + 30\,\% + 5\,\% + 30\,\% = 100\,\%
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.29\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.29\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.29\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
29\,\% + 5\,\% + 29\,\% + 5\,\% + 29\,\% = 97\,\%
\end{equation}

\pagebreak
\section*{Four Figures}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.2125\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.2125\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.2125\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.2125\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
21.25\,\% + 5\,\% + 21.25\,\% + 5\,\% + 21.25\,\% + 5\,\% +21.25\,\% = 100\,\%
\end{equation}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
\hspace{0.05\textwidth}
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
20\,\% + 5\,\% + 20\,\% + 5\,\% + 20\,\% + 5\,\% +20\,\% = 95\,\%
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

### Question

> What/Which length are taken into account when calculating the total width?

### Solution for the Symptoms

> User **Mico** pointed out that `\hfill` replacing all `\hspace{0.xx\textwidth}`
>   solves the problem/symptom since it's a variable length.

I still don't understand why the calculations don't add up.

### Solution for the Problem

User **Arash Esbati** and user **Mico** found the root cause. I need to mask the line break after `\hspace{0.xx\textwidth}` with a `%` as in `\hspace{0.1\textwidth}%`. The line break adds an extra space that leads to a total width of more than 100 %.

### Related

- [Why does the sum of a partition of 1 not equal 1?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342947)

### Final Solution and Some Additional Examples

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    showframe, % This option shows the margins and so on
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% Here: H option for float placement
\usepackage{float}

% caption and subcaption work together
\usepackage{subcaption} % loads the caption package

\begin{document}

\section{Two Figures}
\subsection{Horizontal}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Vertical}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\section{Three Figures}
\subsection{Horizontal}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Vertical}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Mixed}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\section{Four Figures}
\subsection{Horizontal}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Mixed}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\section{Symmetric Padding}

See the following example with small picture widths.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

You can use the optional argument of the \texttt{\textbackslash subcaptionbox} in order to define the width of the sub element.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}[0.50\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}[0.50\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}[0.50\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-C}}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}[0.50\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

Here I try to illustrate the idea behind the solution -- \textbf{don't use this code}!

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\fbox{%
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}[0.482\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\fbox{%
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}[0.482\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
}%
\\ % <-- Line break
\fbox{%
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}[0.482\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
}%
\hfill % <-- Seperation
\fbox{%
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}[0.482\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image}}%
}%
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Comment: @hooy Better? ;)

Comment: Why are you using `\hspace{0.1\textwidth}` instead of `\hfill`?

Comment: @Mico Good question :). This helps! I updated the question. Is the original question (why the deterministic calculation doesn't work) still worth it? I would appreciate it.

Comment: You get one extra space after `\hspace{0.1\textwidth}` and that kills your calculation.  Hide the line ends there with `%` and try again.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Provide an answer and I'll accept. Stupid me... I also updated the question and included your answer.

Comment: See [Why does the sum of a partition of 1 not equal 1?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/342947/5001) for a related query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For want of a nail the shoe was lost,
>
> for want of a shoe the horse was lost,
>
> for want of a horse the knight was lost,
>
> ...

You're missing a `%` character immediately after each and every instance of

```
 \hspace{<some fraction of \textwidth>}
```

Supply those characters, and everthing will be OK, the kingdom won't be lost, and everyone will live happily ever after.

That said, I'd say it must be easier to type `\hfill` (with or without a terminating `%` character) than to engage in explicit length calculations to determine the arguments of `\hspace`.

A full MWE, using `\hfill`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption} % load 'caption' automatically
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\caption{Two subfigures}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
\caption{Three subfigures}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption A}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.225\textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption B}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.225\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption C}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.225\textwidth]{example-image-c}}%
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Subcaption D}{%
\includegraphics[width=0.225\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\caption{Four subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: **Thanks.** Another comment pointed in the same direction. I also updated the question. I should have solved this myself... :).

Comment: I also updated the code in the question (I summarized your solution since I didn't know that you also will update your answer). In Figure 10 I also address a different "problem" and provide a solution.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Sorry it took me a few minutes to supply and MWE.