# Newbie - How to get 3 images onto 1 slide with 2 on top and one underneath

Tags: beamer, graphics

I have this small example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Boadilla}     
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \usefonttheme{structurebold}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
} 

\usepackage{array,amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.28\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=1 1.75 3 1, width=50mm,scale=0.35]{Image1}
     \caption{Substrate-Enzyme association}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.28\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=1 1.75 3 1, width=50mm,scale=0.35]{Image2}
    \caption{Complex dissociation}
  \end{subfigure} \\
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=1 1.75 3 1, width=50mm,scale=0.35]{Image3}
    \caption{Product formation}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Prior and posterior after 100, 200 and 300 reactions for reaction in Micahelis-Menten model}
  \label{fig:boat2}
\end{figure}
\begin{itemize}
\item as more reactions take place, posterior becomes narrower 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

And I am trying to get these images to align so that I have 2 images on my top row, then the 3rd image and the following line and centred between the 2 top images.

But everything I try the formatting keeps getting worse and worse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Figures: What is the difference between using subfig or subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122314/figures-what-is-the-difference-between-using-subfig-or-subfigure)

Comment: Hi. I added a related question - I think that the answers there are enough to solve your issue.

Comment: In principle your code does that, except for the `trim` arguments of the `\includegraphics` commands, meaning that there are conflicting directives `width=50mm` and `scale=0.35`. Try with only one of those.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361579

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of piling up questions (most of them have answers) you should also accept answers and vote for them, in order to appreciate the work done by users to help you... anything other is pure exploitation

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of columns:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Boadilla}     
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \usefonttheme{structurebold}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
} 

\usepackage{array,amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\centering
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=1 1.75 3 1, width=30mm,scale=0.3]{Image1}
     \caption*{Substrate-Enzyme association}
  \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{figure}[b]
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=1 1.75 3 1, width=30mm,scale=0.3]{Image2}
    \caption*{Complex dissociation}
  \end{figure} 
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\vspace{-10px}  
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[b]
      \includegraphics[clip, trim=1 1.75 3 1, width=30mm,scale=0.3]{Image3}
      \caption*{Product formation}
  \end{figure}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\vspace{-20px}  
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \caption{\centering{}Prior and posterior after 100, 200 and 300 reactions for reaction in Micahelis-Menten model}
  \label{fig:boat2}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-25px}
\begin{itemize}
\item as more reactions take place, posterior becomes narrower 
\end{itemize}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

[image: g]

Comment: Welcome! This definitely seems more Beamer-like. I'm not clear whether the OP wants the gap in the top row or not, but I agree that the question does seem to ask for the third on a new line.

Answer (score 3):

Some comments and observations:

- In a `beamer` document, `figure` and `table` environments don't float.
- Indeed, in a `beamer` document, there's little point in employing `figure` and `table` environments -- other than, say, as containers for `subfigure` and `subtable` environments, I suppose. Oh, and just place the caption material in the argument of `\frametitle`.
- If you really want to fit all three graphs *and* the `itemize` environment in a single frame, you will almost certainly have to place all three graphs side by side, rather than 2 on the first row and the third on the second row.
- In the code you provided, the width and scale options of the `\includegraphics` directives are in conflict with each other. Use only option, but not both.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer} % omit 'demo' option in real document
%% I've taken the liberty of streamling and de-duplicating the preamble.
\mode<presentation>%
{ \usetheme{Boadilla}     
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \usefonttheme{structurebold}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball] } 
\usepackage{array,mathtools,booktabs}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Prior and posterior after 100, 200 and 300 reactions for reaction in Micahelis-Menten model}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[clip, trim=1 1.75 3 1, width=\textwidth]{Image1}
     \caption{Substrate-Enzyme association}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=1 1.75 3 1, width=\textwidth]{Image2}
    \caption{Complex dissociation}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[clip, trim=1 1.75 3 1, width=\textwidth]{Image3}
    \caption{Product formation}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{itemize}
\item As more reactions take place, posterior becomes narrower.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know `graphicx` is loaded by beamer already, otherwise `\includegraphics` with overlay syntax would be pretty useless. (I know, the OP has the loading in his/her example)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Good point! Indeed, the `beamer` class loads `graphicx` automatically. I've edited the preamble to heave off one more package-loading directive.

Comment: Isn't the third image supposed to be below the first two?

Comment: @cfr - please see the third bulletpoint in my answer. :-)

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry - missed that. I guess I'm even less clear what the OP actually wants the more I re-read the question.