# How to move image upwards to fit on slide

Tags: beamer, graphics, formatting

I have this example

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Boadilla}     
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \usefonttheme{structurebold}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
} 

\usepackage{array,amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe} % for blindtext and example-image-a in example
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Inference}

\begin{itemize}
\item Independent gamma priors:
\end{itemize}
\begin{gather*}
 \pi(c) = \prod\limits_{j=1}^v \pi(c_j), \quad c_j \sim Ga(a_j, b_j), \; j=1,...,v
\end{gather*}
\begin{itemize}
\item Prior combined with our likelihood gives us updated posteriors:
\end{itemize}
\begin{gather*}
c_j|\mathbf {x} \sim Ga\Big(a_j+r_j,b_j+\int_0^Tg_j(x(t))\,dt \Big), \; j=1,..,v
\end{gather*}
\begin{columns}
 \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
\begin{itemize}
\item Simulate our system to get perfect information
\item Graph shows simulated data for 300 reactions of our Micahelis-Menten model
\end{itemize}
 \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/PresentationGraphics/Simulateddatagraph.pdf}
%  \captionof{figure}{Simulated data for 300 reactions\label{fig:boat1}}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

And my image just doesn't fit on the slide. I don't want to make my image smaller because then people wont be able to see it.

I have tried text wrapping my image but that doesn't seem to work either.

I have also tried searching for a similar question but I really couldn't find anything that helped.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to your image. However, you *may* get what you want by replacing both `\column` commands by `\column[b]`.

Comment: Please consider this comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415003/newbie-how-to-get-3-images-onto-1-slide-with-2-on-top-and-one-underneath#comment1036929_415003

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that your image is to height ... with example image from `graphicx` package and rewriting your frame i managed to show complete image on slide:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Boadilla}
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \usefonttheme{structurebold}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
}

\usepackage{array,amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{mwe} % for blindtext and example-image-a in example
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Inference}
    \begin{itemize}% <--- changed
\item Independent gamma priors:
\[
 \pi(c) = \prod\limits_{j=1}^v \pi(c_j), \quad c_j \sim Ga(a_j, b_j), \; j=1,...,v
\]
\item Prior combined with our likelihood gives us updated posteriors:
\[
c_j|\mathbf {x} \sim Ga\Big(a_j+r_j,b_j+\int_0^Tg_j(x(t))\,dt \Big), \; j=1,..,v
\]
    \end{itemize}

\begin{columns}
 \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{itemize}
\item Simulate our system to get perfect information
\item Graph shows simulated data for 300 reactions of our Micahelis-Menten model
    \end{itemize}
 \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}%{C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/PresentationGraphics/Simulateddatagraph.pdf}
%  \captionof{figure}{Simulated data for 300 reactions\label{fig:boat1}}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a negative \vspace before the graphic to move it up:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Boadilla}
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}
  \usefonttheme{structurebold}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
}

\usepackage{array,amsmath,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe} % for blindtext and example-image-a in example
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Inference}

\begin{itemize}
\item Independent gamma priors:
\end{itemize}
\begin{gather*}
 \pi(c) = \prod\limits_{j=1}^v \pi(c_j), \quad c_j \sim Ga(a_j, b_j), \; j=1,...,v
\end{gather*}
\begin{itemize}
\item Prior combined with our likelihood gives us updated posteriors:
\end{itemize}
\begin{gather*}
c_j|\mathbf {x} \sim Ga\Big(a_j+r_j,b_j+\int_0^Tg_j(x(t))\,dt \Big), \; j=1,..,v
\end{gather*}
\begin{columns}
 \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
\begin{itemize}
\item Simulate our system to get perfect information
\item Graph shows simulated data for 300 reactions of our Micahelis-Menten model
\end{itemize}
 \column{0.5\textwidth}\centering
\begin{figure}
\vspace{-10cm}%adapt
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
%  \captionof{figure}{Simulated data for 300 reactions\label{fig:boat1}}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```